# Conditional Operator on variable assignment in VBA

Tags: c#, excel, vba

In C# you can assign a value to a variable and do a comparison at the same time like this:

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());  
string classify;

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input > 0) ? "positive" : "negative";
```

"classify" now has the value of "positive" or "negative" depending on the input provided

Is there an equivalent to this in VBA? I know I can do an If statement to compare it and assign the value, I am trying to see if it can be simplified to a single line.

Comment: Thanks, I searched for "Conditional Operator" and I couldn't get an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the IIF() function:

```
Dim inpt As Double
inpt = Application.InputBox("give me a number", Type:=1)

Dim classify As String
classify = IIf(inpt > 0, "Positive", "Negative")
MsgBox classify
```

One thing to remember with the IIF function, it will resolve all portions of the function.  So even if the test returns true it will try to process the false and the true, but only return the true.

What that means is if one of the returns causes an error it will error regardless if it is the value to be returned or not.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I am looking for, testing it.